# SELECT * FROM Table gives an error about Arithmetic overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I had problem when I execute this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY column1, column2
```

I got error about **Arithmetic overflow**. I found which column is the problem, that is `somecolumn` which is numeric(10, 0) but in some rows consists more than 10 digits, and don't ask me how is even happened because I don't know :)

I just delete enough digits, to make column have max 10 digits, and that is solved error on that error, but problem is that there is around 100 such rows.

Question is: what can cause such problem, and how to write right SQL statement to select those rows?

It seems to me that problem eventually may be some way of truncating values in column. This is only assumption: maybe column first was numeric(20, 0), and consist values with 10 or 11 digits, but then someone decide that this column must be changed to numeric(10, 0) and then problem appear. This is just some assumption.

Comment: Is `somecolumn` a computed column by any chance?

Comment: No, classic numeric column, without formula, and not persisted.

Comment: how is the column defined, and what is the value in the column? I want to try to create table here with same issue.

Comment: Column is defined like `numeric(10, 0)` and values in it are like `1122334455`, `11223344551`, `11223344552`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just ALTER this column?
Or you can also try convert it like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(bigint,(somecolumn))  
FROM Table1  
ORDER BY column1, column2
```

Comment: I can't just alter column, because, I don't have permission to do that. Convert don't work, same error.

Comment: haven't permission for ALTER or for table? if this table only, i think you can make SELECT * INTO... new temp table and work with it

Comment: Whenever I select this column, I got error, so this solution wouldn't work. By the way, creating temp table for few million or rows may be performance degradation